# Runtime dependency not found but it's there in the runtime path?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, rpath

I am trying to run my application which requires a dependency `libother`; and `libother` requires its own dependency `libfftw3`. Both dependencies are located in the same folder on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I build my application using Qt and specify the runtime path inside my `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

# Library runtime location
unix{
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\'"
}

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Include path
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include/

# Libraries
LIBS += -L$$PWD/bin/ -lother
```

What is so strange is that when I run the application, it is able to find the one dependency and not the other even though they are both located in the same place specified by `-rpath`:

```
ldd my_app

libother.so.1 => /my_app_path/libother.so.1     # Path specified by -rpath
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6    # System lib path
libfftw3.so.3.6.9 => not found    # This lib is in the same location as libother.so.1 but isn't found?
```

If I manually add `my_path` to my runtime path, then it loads fine. It just makes no sense.

Comment: You should really be showing us the important parts of what you're doing - namely the actual compile and link statements, or at least the Makefile, CMakeLists.txt or whatever Qt equivalent would let people deduce those commandlines.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I have added the contents of my .pro file which is used by `QMake`.

Comment: I don't see any explanation in your .pro file for why the program is linked against libfftw3 at all.  How does that dependency arise?

Comment: @JohnBollinger `libother` requires `libfftw3` at runtime. The config for `libother` is pretty much the exact same except being linked to `libfftw3`. Everything also works fine on Windows leading me to believe it's an issue with the Linux build of the libraries or the `-rpath`.

Comment: Well then, does `libother` have an `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` entry?

Comment: @JohnBollinger No it does not. Since it's a library I didn't really think about it.

Comment: I anticipate that when the dynamic linker needs to load libraries referenced by `libother`, and which have not already been loaded, it will consider `libother`'s `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`, if any, not those of the dynamic object providing the program's entry point.  ELF shared libraries are subject to their own dynamic linking.

Comment: If libfftw3 is needed at runtime, then it's normal that you app cannot find it if your RPATH doesn't point to the folder containing the dll.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are correct. I added `-rpath` when building `libother` and now it's working fine. Kindly add your comment as an answer so that I may mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RPATH` and `RUNPATH` apply to resolving shared objects directly listed as needed by the same shared object in which they themselves appear.  Those have their own lists of needed shared objects, and (only) their own `RPATH` or `RUNPATH` entries are used to resolve references to those.  This was apparently your issue.  Your main executable object did not link directly to libfftw3, so its `RPATH` was not relevant to loading it.  Your `libother` did link to `libfftw3`, but it did not have an `RPATH` entry by which to locate that library outside the default library search path.